# 3Sum using python3 and enumarate

Tags: python-3.x

I want to solve the following task using 'enumerate' in python3

The way enumerate works is demonstrated below

```
nums=(2,7,1,15)               # a tuple  

for num in enumerate(nums):
        print(num, 'hello')   

#output
#(0, 2) hello        #enumarate(nums) = (0,2)
#(1, 7) hello
#(2, 1) hello
#(3, 15) hello      


for count, num in enumerate(nums):
        print(num, 'hello')      

# Output
#2 hello    here count=0 but not displayed 
#7 hello    here count=1 but not displayed
#1 hello    here count=2 but not displayed
#15 hello   here count=3 but not displayed
```

Using the above principle, given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = target sum? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum = target sum.

A solution set for target sum =10  is:

```
[
  [0,1,2]             
]
```

where num at 0th index+num at 1st index+num at 2nd index(7+2+1=10).

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use enumerate? Because people who will answer your question know about enumerate and do not need an explanation, and it is very possible that given answers do not use enumerate.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that is your point of view. It is not homework

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yes, I need to use enumerate. There are other solutions which I am aware of to solve this task. I am curious how would enumerate behave under this condition

Comment: The reason it looks like homework is that it starts with a preamble that I've never seen outside a comp sci class.

Comment: @MadPhysicist your premise is incorrect. Please look at my previous questions I am not a student in CS class.

Comment: Please post relevant code. You mentioned alternative solutions. Those would help. So would an attempt to solve the specific problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an idea for an algorithm to solve the problem?

I would probably do something like build up two `dict`s listing all the ways to use the array indexes make a sum with 1 number and 2 numbers to be a certain key value.

E.g., if I had been given `nums = [2, 7, 1, 2, 3]`, I would write code to build up a table like:

```
one_sum = {1: [2], 
           2: [0, 3], 
           3: [4],
           7: [1]}
```

I would use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from collections module to efficiently write this code (initialized as `one_sum = defaultdict(list)` above, though a `set` would also be a valid data structure for the problem).

It would be straightforward to use `enumerate` for this part; e.g.,

```
for i, n in enumerate(nums):
    one_sum[n].append(i)
```

Then I would then build up a `two_sum` table this time showing all pairs of indexes that make a certain sum.  Continuing with the example above, I would want to generate:

```
two_sum = {3: [(0, 2), (2, 3)],
           4: [(2, 4)],
           5: [(0, 4), (3, 4)],
           8: [(1, 2)],
           9: [(0, 1), (1, 3)],
          10: [(1, 4)]}
```

(Note one way to efficiently do this is to loop through the built up `one_sum`, but be careful not to re-use an index e.g., don't add `(2,2)` or `(4,4)` to `two_sum[4]` because while `nums[2] + nums[2]` does add up to 4, it uses an index twice (so isn't unique).  Also be careful not to double add indexes that are out of order.)

Finally I would loop through the `one_sum` dict, looking at indices that sum to `k` and then look in `two_sum` to see if there are any pairs of indices that sum to `target-k`, and if so then join the pairs together (checking to sort indices and not repeat indices in a tuple) having found a solution.

For a target of 10 this would ideally build up

```
three_sum = [(0,1,2), (1,2,3)]

# Note both were added from combining one_sum[1] with two_sum[9]
# nothing from combining one_sum[2] with two_sum[8] as they reuse indexes
# nothing from combining one_sum[3] as two_sum[7]==[]
# nothing new from combining one_sum[7] with two_sum[3] as (0,1,2) and (1,2,3) already present.
```

Comment: Neat. O(n) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force method. It's not as efficient as this algorithm can be, mind you.

```
def f(nums, target):
    sols = []
    for i1, n1 in enumerate(nums):
        for i2, n2 in enumerate(nums[i1+1:]):
            for i3, n3 in enumerate(nums[i2+1:]):
                if (n1 + n2 + n3 == target):
                    sols.append([i1, i2, i3])
    return sols
```

Comment: I didn't give an optimal solution. They'll still have to work on this. It does show how to use enumerate.

Comment: @MadPhysicist don't judge the question because it looks homework to you. I have solved this question using other methods and was able to get the solution. I wanted to know how would enumerate behave if I had to solve this task

Comment: Yup.  Please note this answer won't work as is.  (`target` undefined, need to properly start the counts in enumerate).